# Cannot find module app.js when debugging nodejs on VSCode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I created a Nodejs with VScode and encountered the above Problem when I wanted to debug the app.

Problem:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'f:\xxx\MyNodeJS\app.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:194:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:618:3
```

I have setup to use index.js

below is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "mynodejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "stripe": "^8.60.0"
  }
}
```

update:

```
{
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",
        "request": "launch",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "type": "pwa-node"
    }
    ]
}
```

What I need to do? your help is greatly apreciated. Thanks

Comment: `package.json` gives no help when importing js files that you create. what command are you running to spawn this error? Can you validate that your import of `app.js` in whatever code you have is referencing the correct path?

Comment: @LostJon  I create a launch.json file for nodejs as shown in my above update. and I select launch program and click the run-icon

Comment: oh I see, I didnt change app.js to index.js

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem of .vscode/launch.json configuration. The "program" property must point to an executable or file to run when launching the debugger. The [doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes) provides "app.js" as an example, it needs to be updated:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/index.js"
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```